# How to display a QImage in QWebKit?

Tags: qt, qimage, qwebkit

Is there any way to display a QImage (in memory, not on filesystem) in a QWebFrame without writing the image out to a temporary file?

Answer (score 3):

One option might be using the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). You basically base64 encode your picture and write the complete data into the URL.
For example:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

WebKit should support these URIs either directly, or as part of a HTML source code, like

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,blaBLABLA" />
```

Be aware: if your image is big, you might be running into some constraints. Usually this used more for small stuff like icons.

Answer (score 0):

Damn. Steffen beat me to it! :)

To add, you could convert to base 64 by saving the image to a QBuffer(&byteArray) and then saying byteArray.toBase64()